# Nginx/SNI: Return 444 if there's no certificate available for a specific domain hosted on the same IP

Tags: ssl, https, nginx

I'm stuck with configuring nginx regarding SSL and SNI support.

In order to simplify my case let's say I have two domains, `foo.com` and `bar.com`. I have only one IP and both domains are mapped to this one. I want `foo.com` to be available via `https`, but not `bar.com`. The latter should just be unavailable on port 443. I know this is not possible with plain SSL but I was told that I can safely rely on SNI these days. So I assume that my browser (Chrome) sends the domain of the website it wants to access alongside the SSL init request.

If I access `bar.com`, nginx uses the configured certificate issued for `bar.com`, perfect. If I access `https://foo.com`, for which no `listen *:443` directive actually exists, nginx also replies with the certificate for `bar.com`, thus Chrome throws a certificate exception. I tried to configure the SSL listen directive for `foo.com` and added the following code in the vhost with no success:

```
if ($server_port = 443) {
  return 444;
}
```

It now sends the wrong certificate and only afterwards denies the connection.

Is it possible to let nginx close the connection before any SSL reply is sent back to the browser if nginx cannot find an appropriate certificate for the requested domain?

Comment: After a TLS session has been requested, it is not possible to deny it gracefully.

Comment: Well, I do not want to deny it gracefully. Just drop the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx uses the first appropriate (by port and ssl presence) virtual host when it can't find a virtual host for the given domain. You need to add a `server {}` entry **before** all the other `server {}` entries so that Nginx will use it for `https://foo.com` and other HTTPS requests with an unknown domain:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certificate.key;

    return 404;
    # or return 444; to just drop such connections
    # or return 302 http://$host$request_uri; to redirect them to HTTP
}
```

It needs a SSL certificate to work but you can [generate a self-signed one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-16-04) (the certificate is not required to be valid).